# ReactNative - unable to call function from native module

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I have existing ReactNative project.

Now I'm trying to connect to some native libraries. I've been going through official [Native modules guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content).

In my code I've added CalendarManager.h file which contains this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface CalendarManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

I also have CalendarManager.m file:

```
#import "CalendarManager.h"

@implementation CalendarManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString*)location)
{
   //RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}

@end
```

This files are added at same level as AppDelegate.m file via XCode.

In my javascript code i do this:

```
import React from 'react-native';
```

And then i call that function like this:

```
var cmanager = React.CalendarManager;
cmanager.addEvent('Birthday Party', '4 Privet Drive, Surrey');
```

I'm able to build the project, but when I run it in Simulator (after package manager starts) I get nasty red error:

```
Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined.
```

It looks to me that I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `NativeModules` to reach your custom native components.

Try this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var CalendarManager = NativeModules.CalendarManager;
CalendarManager.addEvent('Birthday Party', '4 Privet Drive, Surrey');
```

Comment: Of course. I was missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: It Works Thanks for Solution.